# How to prevent users from seeing other users within the same Organization, but on separate team projects in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I am setting up an Azure DevOps organization with separate team projects. I don't want users to be able to go to "Organization Settings" -> "Permissions" -> "Users" page and see all the users in the Organization and their email addresses.

I've tried setting the "View Instance-Level Information" permission to "Deny" for a user, but they can still see it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to prevent users from seeing all users within "Users" page?

For this issue, I am afraid this feature is currently not supported in azure devops.
Users in the organization can see all members from the "Users" page.

You could raise your feature demand [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to promote development of richer features.

After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.